# floated div goes down when i enter more text

Tags: html

When i enter text in my div he goes under the picture. If i enter just couple of words DIV floats next to picture. Where is the problem?

```css
.container {
        width: 250px;
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .container img {
        float: left;
    }
    .inside {
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="lib/images/asd-261269281.jpg" width="92" height="92">
    <div class="inside">text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what is wrong. Can you elaborate on what you want it to do and then what it is actually doing?

Comment: That is because the `.inside` element doen't have a fixed width. The more text you put inside, the more wider it gets. If its width plus the image width is bigger than the container width, it will go down because it has no more space.

Comment: is there any way to do it without setting width for div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you..:D

```css
.container {
        width: 250px;
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .container img {
        float: left;
    }
    .inside {
        float: left;
        max-width:138px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="lib/images/asd-261269281.jpg" width="92" height="92">
    <div class="inside">text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your image as a background. That way you can fill it with text.

Like so:

```
<div class="container">text text text text</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8b8zatm/)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your text is overflowing the bounds of the defined box when you add more text so it is moved to below the image. There are a couple of different options that you have available here. You can set the width of the inside class so that it will wrap the text instead.

```
.inside {
    float: left;
    width: 55%; // Defines the max width of the box before it can wrap vertically.
}
```

A second method you can use is to set the display type of the .inside class to [inline-block](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/):

```
.inside {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 55%;
}
```